# jqplot multiple bar/line chart allignment

Tags: jquery, charts, rendering, jqplot

I have created the following chart using jqplot.

[image]

I would like align the blue line with the blue bar chart and the red line with the red bar chart.By align I mean that the 'bullet' of the line chart, which shows the value, would be aligned with the bar chart horizontally.

Is this possible? I know that it would be possible if I would stack the bar charts one on top of the other. But if I would like the bar charts to be displayed as they are here... is it possible then?

Thank you for any answer...